# Scala 2.11 Spark 2.0 hortonworks-spark/shc sbt assemby

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I try to assembly a Scala 2.11 Spark 2.0 application using [hortonworks-spark/shc](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/tree/v1.0.1-2.0) to access hbase.

The dependencies set looks simple:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2" % "provided",
  "com.hortonworks" % "shc-core" % "1.0.1-2.0-s_2.11"
)
```

The problem comes when I try to assembly the application in a Fat jar, because there are a lot of transience dependencies with different version, then the assembly plugin throw duplicate errors. One example:

```
deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/search/.ivy2/cache/org.mortbay.jetty/jsp-2.1/jars/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar:org/apache/jasper/xmlparser/XMLString.class
[error] /home/search/.ivy2/cache/tomcat/jasper-compiler/jars/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:org/apache/jasper/xmlparser/XMLString.class
```

Also, I don't know if it is right include in the jar dependencies like org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:1.1.2

So, basically, the question is: Anyone know the right way to assembly an Scala Spark application using this library and sbt and can provide an example? (And maybe add it in the documentation of [hortonworks-spark/shc](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/tree/v1.0.1-2.0)

Note: [hortonworks-spark/shc](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/tree/v1.0.1-2.0) is not include in [spark-packages](https://spark-packages.org/) so I can not use the --packages option if it is not with a local copy of the jars. I am using EMR, so I don't have a preconfigured cluster where copy the jar without add more complexity to the deployment.

Comment: Could you describe in question which problem come when you assemble fat jar?

Comment: @ipoteka i'm sorry. Added one error example.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify mergeStrategy mentioned in [Readme](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy). And you can provide common libraries on spark nodes instead of including them in fat.jar each time. The rought way to do it is to upload them on each worker and add to classpath.

Comment: I am using EMR, so it is a new cluster every time that execute the application. That is the reason because I want to use a fat jar, to avoid to upload and configure the cluster every new deployment. Also I know how to configure the assembly plugin, but It is a crazy job with the big set of dependencies and conflicts. So I don't know what to do. What do you think?

Comment: @angelcervera When I worked with spark, I provided the simplest mergeStrategy and upload 150mb of my application each run. It was fast and reliable for me. The only problem was when version of library (like json4s) differs between spark and my application. But it's just personal experience.

Comment: Yes, I am used to do the same in hadoop applications.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see jasper-xmlparser is being used by two different jars. So the duplicate. You can exclude the reference from one of them as follows

For example : 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "0.98.12-hadoop2" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.mortbay.jetty")

And regarding adding all dependencies into fat jar, atleast for spark applications, that is the suggested way of handling the jar assembly.
The most common jars(like spark, hbase etc) can be made part of the class path on the edge node or which ever node you are running. Any other specific jars, can be part of uber jar. You can make the spark/hbase jars as provided.

Well at the core, the following should help you to do basic operations.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "0.98.12-hadoop2" // % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "0.98.12-hadoop2"  //% "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "0.98.12-hadoop2" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.mortbay.jetty")
```

Comment: As I responsed to @ipoteka, with the mental set of dependencies it is crazy to exclude or set the scope to all libraries and to be sure that it is ok. Because I think that access to hbase from spark is a commons use (now I doubt) I believed that there was a copy&paste configuration. If not, I will do it because it is necessary.

Comment: Updated my answer to include basic hbase jars. If you are using any other commonly provided jar like hbase-spark, then that will handle all the transitive dependencies. But they will be included in you uber jar

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide mergeStrategy in build.sbt,

It looks something like this,

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

In this example I have specified **MergeStrategy.first** . There are few other options like **MergeStrategy.last** and **MergeStrategy.concat**

MergeStrategy.first means it will select the first jar it sees for a given  dependency to create an uber jar.

*For some of the cases it may not work, if that is the case please try with 
MergeStrategy.last also.*

Comment: I think that it is not a good idea to do this, because I am going to pick the first one up, no matter which is his content.  Check the example. Which is the right class, the included inside jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar or inside jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar? I am asking for the right assembly configuration.

Comment: In my view, one of the first or last should work for you. Once you know which one works, then it should not be a problem.